# kube-dns fails to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I'm trying to install k8s on AWS with kops. The k8s cluster fails to come on line because the kube-dns service keeps crashing. Logs:

```
I0111 19:21:30.189260 1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0111 19:21:30.189278 1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0111 19:21:30.689342 1 dns.go:174] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
...
E0111 19:22:00.189691 1 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/dns/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://100.64.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 100.64.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0111 19:22:00.190016 1 reflector.go:199] k8s.io/dns/vendor/k8s.io/client-go/tools/cache/reflector.go:94: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://100.64.0.1:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 100.64.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

All the user kube-system pods are in good order. The api-server log on the master server doesn't list any errors. What might the problem be?

Comment: Is your CNI plugin running and healthy? Looks like an internal networking problem to me.